# Will SiteEdit 2009 SP3 work with Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, 2013-sp1, siteedit-2009

We are planning to upgrade from Tridion 2011 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1, currently we have SiteEdit 2009 SP3 implemented.  Currently considering project timelines we want to continue with current implementation of SiteEdit.  Will SiteEdit 2009 SP3 work with Tridion 2013 SP1?

Our implementation: 
We are not using out-of-box TBB provide by SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 for enabling SiteEdit.
We have JSP Page Templates maintained in Tridion CMS, each Page Tempaltes outputs below block.

```
<!-- SITE_EDIT_INIT --><!-- Page Settings: { "PageID":"tcmidofpage","PageModified":"PageModifieddatetime","PageTemplateID":"PageTemplateID"} --> <script type = "text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="CMSServer/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"></script>
```

We have customized TBB which outputs below information for each component presentation on page.

```
<span><!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm of Component", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm of Component Template", "ComponentModified" : " ComponentModified Date Time", "ComponentTemplateModified" : " ComponentTemplateModified  modified date time", "IsRepositoryPublished" : true  } --> .....</span>
```

For field level editing (inline editing) below code part is generated using each .Net assembly created fro individual component template.

```
<span> !-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:Title"} -->.....</span>
```

If we upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1 using above implementation will SiteEdit work properly?

Can we use [Upgrade](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-7B860C39-575F-49B3-8BDE-2AE409D52CD7&addHistory=true&query=Siteedit&scope=&tid=68d8d59a-3061-41f2-b13e-7b4365a49666&filename=GUID-7B860C39-575F-49B3-8BDE-2AE409D52CD7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-7B860C39-575F-49B3-8BDE-2AE409D52CD7&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DSiteedit&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1405412622900&currentQuery=Siteedit&currentScope=) option given on Livecontent site?

If we want to go ahead with upgrade to experience manager

1)  Do we need to update all schema fields to make it inline editable? (Enable For Inline Editing checkbox at schema level)?

2)  Do we need to rewrite/change DWT to read fields using “FieldStartMarker(), FieldValueStartMarker(), FieldValueEndMarker(), FieldEndMarker()” ?

3)  What about fields which are read in .net assembly. (.net assembly is outputting required SiteEdt tags) do we need change .net assemblies as well?

4)  JSP page templates still need to output below tag?

Comment: I've voted to reject your edit because it is a new question. Accept an answer to this question and post a new one.

Answer (score 2):

By default when you install Tridion 2013 sp1 then XPM will also be installed and hence you have to use Tridion 2013 sp1 owns XPM and if suppose you try to incorporate the old version of site edit in 2013 sp1 then that will not be supported.

And also why do you want to use some old version of XPM with latest Tridion version as you could achieve more features and functionality from the latest version of XPM.

Comment: Yesterday I did not had access to current implemenation, today I got it, so added details about current implementation

Answer (score 1):

No, SiteEdit will **not** work with SDL Tridion 2013 or higher. You can upgrade to Experience Manager relatively easy (need to change the Building Blocks in your templates, and republish), and if you don't use Session Preview there's not many infra requirements (I do advise using Session Preview though, only suggesting this to accelerate implementation).

**UPDATE**

You'll have to compare the outputs to be sure 100%. I know it's still backwards compatible for fields because the [DGX](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx) still works just fine with XPM, but some things have changed for Page and Component Presentation markup:

- The Page markup is slightly different from before, as it points to a different URL on the CM
- The Component Presentation Markup has moved from being part of the page output to become part of the CP output itself (making it much easier when dealing with DCPs).

The architecture is substantially different too, as there is no more SE proxy.

Comment: Yesterday I did not had access to current implemenation, today I got it, so added details about current implementation