# What all changes required if we want to upgrade from siteedit 2009 sp3 to Experience manager

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, 2013-sp1, siteedit-2009

We are planning to upgrade from Tridion 2011 SP1 to Tridion 2013 SP1, currently we have SiteEdit 2009 SP3 implemented. We want to upgrade siteedit 2009 SP3 to Experience Manager.

Our implementation: We are not using out-of-box TBB provide by SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 for enabling SiteEdit. We have JSP Page Templates maintained in Tridion CMS, each Page Tempaltes outputs below block.

We have customized TBB which outputs below information for each component presentation on page.

.....

For field level editing (inline editing) below code part is generated using each .Net assembly created fro individual component template.

!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:Title"} -->.....

We want to go ahead with upgrade to experience manager but we have below queries.

1. Do we need to update all schema fields to make it inline editable? (Enable For Inline Editing checkbox at schema level)?
2. Do we need to rewrite/change DWT to read fields using
   “FieldStartMarker(), FieldValueStartMarker(), FieldValueEndMarker(),
   FieldEndMarker()”?
3. What about fields which are read in .net assembly. (.net assembly is outputting required SiteEdt tags) do we need change .net assemblies as well?
4. JSP page templates still need to output above mentioned page settings tag?

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, we went though this post, but didn't find answer to point number 2 and 3 hence thought to put new question.

Comment: I think Raj's answer covered that too - in bold - None of your Site Edit related tag will work. Any thing which is not related to Site Edit will work as per the compatibility of your Tridion Version

Comment: Also there is one more question which almost similer to current one http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7228/will-siteedit-2009-sp3-work-with-tridion-2013-sp1

Comment: Regarding #2, the previous DWT functions have been deprecated but still work. The `FieldStartMarker()` and related functions are only to enable adding embedded multivalue fields in XPM. You can but don't have to change the markup now.